# How to refresh WPF datagrid with dragged and dropped binding which contains database view?

Tags: c#, wpf, database, datagrid, observablecollection

I have following database structure.

```
Table:Books
Column: bookid;(PK)
Column: book_title;
Column: isbn;
Column: author_id;(FK)
Column: publisher_id;(FK)
```

The above table is connected via foreign key with another two table named "publishers" and "authors". They are defined as follows.

```
Table:Publishers
Column: publisher_id;(PK)
Column: publisher_title;


Table:Authors
Column: Author_id;(PK)
Column: Author_title;
```

i created database view which is:

```
view:book_info
Column: bookid;
Column: book_title;
Column: isbn;
Column: publisher_title;
Column: Author_title;
```

now what i did is, i dragged and dropped this view as datagrid in WPF window. I get required view. I have tried to use observable collection on a simple grid which is bound to table. Now how to use this observable collection on a grid which has its ItemsSource as view from database?

> I have not written any code yet as i am still confuse how do i update
>   and refresh this grid?

Answer (score 1):

Well things fall in place in unexpected way. My friend found out that the entity is not being updated even if the updates are made. So we created new entity of the same. See below code.

```
//the first declaration on the top.
bookDatabaseEntities bde = new bookDatabaseEntities();

//wrote this code where i need to assign itemssource.This will fetch updates and overwrite older entity created earlier.
bde = new bookDatabaseEntities();
//asssign new view to the grid as itemssource
joinViewsDataGrid.ItemsSource = bde.JoinViews;
```

this worked for me, for my case.